# Symmetries of Archimedean Solids

Tags: group-theory, geometry, polyhedra, symmetry

There are five platonic solids, and 13/15 (which is correct?) [Archimedean Solids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_solid). The finite groups of isometries of Euclidean $3$-space are the finite subgroups of $SO(3,\mathbb{R})$ or $O(3,\mathbb{R})=SO(3,\mathbb{R})\times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

**Question:** List all the finite subgroups of $O(3,\mathbb{R})$. Further, which groups are the full group of symmetries of Archimedean solids.

[I am familiar with finite subgroups of $SO(3,\mathbb{R})$, which are symmetry groups of platonic solids. I want to consider finite subgroups of $O(3,\mathbb{R})$ and their connection with Archimedean solids.]

Comment: Well, the very Wikipedia page by your link gives the symmetries of all bodies, doesn't it? Also, 13 and 15 are both correct.